# How to find what number element $(this) refers to?

Tags: jquery

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            Title
        </th>
        <th>
            Author
        </th>
    <tr>
</table>
```

That's a basic table

```
$("th").click(function(){
    $(this).method();
});
```

All I want to do is call a method when a th tag is clicked but I want to know which one was clicked. So if Title is clicked I want it to return 0 because it's the first element and if Author is clicked return 1 because it's the second element.

I tried putting data-val= on the th tag but this doesn't validate so I removed it.

Comment: Actually data-val is a better approach. What validation errors did you get? Otherwise you can do a very static string compare of $(this).html() == 'Title' and so on... you could do such a static compare with an added id field as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need exactly what you have above, but with `$(this).index()`.  Here's a working fiddle...

http://jsfiddle.net/WNVbn/

Comment: It's a function, needs the `()` to make it a function call.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Doh!  Thanks for spotting my faux pas.  At least the example works ;)